# Codeigniter :A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: codeigniter

in my code their is an error what is solution for this

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/websites/public_html/application/controllers/user.php:64)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 546

this is my code

```
function register()
{
                     $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
                     $cpass=$_POST['cpass'];
            $valid = array(
                                    array(
                                        'field'   => 'email',
                                        'label'   => 'Username(Email)',
                                        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[register.email]'
                                    ), 
                                    array(
                                        'field'   => 'pass',
                                        'label'   => 'Password',
                                        'rules'   => 'trim|required||matches[cpass]|min_length[8]|max_length[30]|'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'field'   => 'cpass',
                                        'label'   => 'Confirm Password',
                                        'rules'   => 'trim|required'
                                    )
                            );
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($valid); 
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error_txt">', '</div>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            echo "error";
            redirect('/home/'); 
        }
        else
        {

            $this->load->model('User_model');       
            $rs=$this->User_model->register($_POST);

            redirect('/home/'); 
        }
}
```

Comment: You should select an answer as the best answer if you found one helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Its probably happening here:

echo "error";

Instead try to return the error to the caller and then display the error from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use redirect in ajax calls. You can achieve your goal with javascript redirect. Try this snippet:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  echo "error";
}
else
{
  $this->load->model('User_model');       
  $rs=$this->User_model->register($_POST);
}
```

In JAVASCRIPT:

```
window.location = '<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect` actually sends a `Location` header to the browser.

Your output has already started. The server has to send the headers before any output is started. You are doing an `echo` before redirect. So its throwing an error as it cant send headers after output has started.

remove that `echo` and it should work for you.